# How to roll-up Custom Object field values onto Standard Campaign Object?

Tags: campaign, roll-up-summary

I want to create custom roll-up summary fields on the `Campaign` object from a custom object/field like `Appointment__c.Price__c` or `Invoice__c.Amount__c`.

But roll-up summary doesn't give me access to any object other than `Campaign Members`.

Do I need to write a `Trigger` or `Batch Job` do achieve this, or is there another way?

Comment: You can create `Roll-Up Summary` field only when you have Master-Detail relationship b/w objects. So here you can achieve this via Workflow or Trigger.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[Declarative Lookup Rollup Summaries](https://github.com/afawcett/declarative-lookup-rollup-summaries) is your friend any time you're seeking to roll up information that's any of

- Not aggregated under a Master-Detail relationship
- Requires filtering more complex than achievable with a native Roll-Up Summary field.
- Uses aggregation operations like Concatenate.
- Uses a standard object as the child.
- Involves objects that don't support triggers (using Scheduled mode).

It's open source and well-tested in many, many orgs. You can achieve this objective without writing a line of Apex.